# Question about finding the dimension of Ker of a matrix!

Tags: linear-algebra

First year student here trying to pass the Linear Algebra exam! Found this in one of the practice quizzes! I tried to find a way to acchive the result but i cant figure it out! Can someone help me?
So the question goes like this!

Let **R^(3,2)** be the vector space of real matrices with 3 rows and 2 columns and **R^(2,2)** be the vector space of real matrices with 2 rows and 2 columns. Let us consider the linear map:

f(X)=(1 2 1, 0 0 0)*X where X∈**R^(3,2)**.
Which of the following statements is true?
A) **f** is sujective;

B)**dim(Ker(f))=2**

C)**dim(Ker(f))=4**

D) f is injective

Tee correct one is C but i cant figure it out how to solve it in case something similar comes up in my exam! Can you help me?

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical formulae. Hint for solving the question: work out what the range of $\mathbb{f}$ is: you will find it comprises the $2\times2$ matrices whose second row is zero. Now you can work out the dimension of the range from which you can calculate the dimension of the kernel (and see that A and D must both be false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any two finite dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with a linear map $\varphi:V \rightarrow W$ the dimension of the image plus the dimension of the kernel will be the dimension of $V$. We also know that the dimension of the image can be no greater than the dimension of $W$. In this case you have a six dimensional space of $3 \times 2$ matrices mapping to the four dimensional space of $2 \times 2$ matrices. The matrix you're given will have an image of the form $$\pmatrix{x & y  \\ 0 & 0}$$ and since the image is two dimensional. This means the dimension of the kernel is $6 - 2 = 4$.